# How to get download speed with NET::HTTP

Tags: ruby, net-http

Is there a way to get current download speed when using NET::HTTP to download files?

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'open-uri'

time  = Time.now

stuff = open('http://www.giovannicapuano.net').read
File.write 'stuff', stuff

time_spent = Time.now - time
file_size  = File.size('stuff') / 1024.0 / 1024.0
speed      = file_size / time_spent
```

or...

```
require 'net/http'

time  = Time.now

uri = URI 'http://www.giovannicapuano.net'
stuff = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri).body
File.write 'stuff', stuff

time_spent = Time.now - time
file_size  = File.size('stuff') / 1024.0 / 1024.0
speed      = file_size / time_spent
```